# jQuery ajax unlimited dynamic selectbox based on parent categories

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have a table for category :

```
| category_id | category_name | parent_id
| 1           | Electronics   | 0
| 2           | Mobile Phones | 1
| 3           | Computers     | 1
| 4           | Iphone        | 2
| 5           | Samsung Galaxy| 2
| 6           | Asus Laptop   | 3
```

So this table is able to store unlimited child category for a parent category.

Now what I'm trying to achieve is, let's say that I choose Electronics, then another selectbox should appear with value list `Mobile Phones` and `Computers`.
And then if  I choose `Computers`, another selectbox will appear with the value list `Asus Laptop`.

I know how to code the dynamic select box, but it doesnt work with unlimited sub-categories.

This one should work like this (based on my thinking).

> 1. User choose a category from the first selectbox
> 2. Send ajax to getcategory.php
> 3. getcategory.php finds out if there is any child category from the user-chosen first category.
> 4. ajax receive data from getcategory.php
> 5. if data exist, jQuery create a new select box and put in the fetched data into it.
> 6. User choose sub-category from the just added selectbox
> 7. Send ajax to getcategory.php
> 8. getcategory.php finds out if there is any more child category from the user-chosen sub-category.
> 9. ajax receive data from getcategory.php
> 10. if data exist, jQuery create a new select box and put in the fetched data into it.
> 11. and so on.. until the selectbox have no child category.

How do I achieve this? Is this the right way? or Is there any other workaround for this? Thank you

Comment: What will be in the first selectbox? Only `Electronics`?

Comment: @MoshFeu Based on the table "category" data. if I put another one "Home and Furnishing", then there will be 2 values in the first selectbox

Comment: @MoshFeu it recognize parent category by parent_id=0

Comment: I understand this. `Home and Furnishing` will be `parent_id` 0 too?

Comment: @MoshFeu yup all the first category will have parent_id=0

Comment: @SIDU answer look pretty good. Isn't?

Comment: @MoshFeu It's not what I asked about, most simple definition about what I want to do is Unlimited Dynamic Category Select Box

Comment: check this http://www.99points.info/2010/12/n-level-dynamic-loading-of-dropdowns-using-ajax-and-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code
1)conf.php

```
<?php
```

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','test') or die(mysqli_error($conn));?>

2)category-dropdown.php

```
<?php
include 'conf.php';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id=0';

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>MultiDropdown</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<select name="category" class="form-control category">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php
foreach($data as $d){
echo '<option value="'.$d['id'].'">'.$d['category'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="dropdown_container"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change','.category',function(){
var id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
url:'getcategory.php',
type:'post',
data:{'id':id},
success:function(data){
//alert(data);
$('#dropdown_container').append(data);
}
})
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

3)getcategory.php

```
<?php
include 'conf.php';
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id= $_POST['id'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = '.$id;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(!empty($data)){
echo '<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<select name="category" class="form-control category">
<option value="">Select</option>';
foreach($data as $d){
echo '<option value="'.$d['id'].'">'.$d['category'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>
</div>
</div>';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the unlimited sub-cats should be no problem: (I m not sure why you have this problem as you said you have no problem in coding)

For unlimited sub-cats you simply calling the same SQL to return sub-cats or null:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id = ?
```

The following is off-topic --------------

It might need a little bit energy if you want to show all products of a selected category and its all children.

You might need change your design to:

```
id     category
------ ----------
11     Electronics
1101   Mobile Phones
1102   Computers
110101 Iphone
110102 Samsung Galaxy
110201 Asus Laptop
```

For above design max 99 child, if you need more, you might increase to 3-digits, etc

case study: find all products that are in category 11 and all its children:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id like '11%'
```

Comment: this query will load all sub categories and sub-sub categories, it is does not match with the question