# PHP Adding dynamic category realtime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm making this project on site where there are list of items and they have id and there are another set of data with the same id as the first one and they each have their id. So I want to show options by getting the id of first one to display other realtime with JQuery or JScript and PHP. My code looks like this

**Categories are**
 1. Electronics
 2. Venues

And Subcategories are for electronics

**Electronics**
 
Hardware
 Software

**Venues**
    
My House
    Friends House

```
<select name="category" id="catagoryid">
    <?php  
        $categories = selectAllData('categories');
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) {
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
            echo "<option value='{$cat_id}'>{$cat_title}</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

And the another set is here

```
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
    <?php  
        $subcategories = selectAllData('subcategories');
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subcategories)) {
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            $sub_cat_id = $row['sub_cat_id'];
            $sub_title = $row['sub_cat_title'];
            echo "<option value='{$sub_cat_id}' title='{$cat_id}'>{$sub_title}</option>";

        };
    ?>  
</select>
```

So far I what I have tried are

```
$('#subcategory').change(function(event) {
    var subcategory = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("title");
    if (subcategory!==categoryid) {
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').val()!==categoryid) {
            $(this).find('option:selected').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

And other approach I have been stuck here from yesterday. I have tried getting value of selected item from JavaScript and running php. But I noticed that php loads before Jscript so there is no way to do this way. There was another approach of running Jscript inside PHP but I couldn't get the value if user selects another item.

Comment: You can not hide `<option>` cross browser. Not supported notably in IE and Safari. Choices are remove/replace or disable/enable

Comment: So what do I do? Is there any other way?

Comment: So you want to display a list of options for a second select box? depending on what the user selected in the first select box?

Comment: Yes that is what I want. As the user can change anytime so I want it to be displayed dynamically fetching from the databse

Comment: If it's not a lot of data... pass it all to javascript (with PHP function json_encode()) on page load. Don't try to query the database after the user has selected something

Comment: Fredster So I pass it in array and depending upon what the user selects I display from array?

Comment: Exactly. Pass it to a Javascript array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is remove and store all the subcategory `<option>` on page load.

Then clone and filter the stored `<option>` and replace what is in the second select when the first is changed.

You can use classes or data attributes as filters

```js
//remove and store subcategory options
var $subCatOpts = $('#subcategory option').detach();

$('#catagoryid').change(function() {
  var catId = this.value;
  // clone stored ones so we always have them available...then filter
  var $opts = $subCatOpts.clone().filter(function() {
    return !this.value || catId === $(this).attr('data-catid')
  });
  $('#subcategory').html($opts)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Category:
<select name="category" id="catagoryid">
  <option value=""> -- Select Category -- </option>
  <option value="1">Electronics</option>
  <option value="2">Venues</option>
</select>

Subcategory
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
  <option value=""> -- Select Sub category -- </option>
  <option value="1" data-catid="1">Electronics - Sub 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-catid="1">Electronics - Sub 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-catid="2">Venues - Sub 1</option>
  <option value="4" data-catid="2">Venues - Sub 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass all the data on page load to browser.

```
  <?php  
     $subcategories_json = array();
        $subcategories = selectAllData('subcategories');
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subcategories)) {
            $subcategories_json[] = array(
               'cat_id' => $row['cat_id'],
               'sub_cat_id' => $row['sub_cat_id'],
               'sub_title' => $row['sub_cat_title']
            );
        }
        echo "<script>subcategories = ".json_encode($subcategories_json).";
  </script>";
 ?>
```

Then in Javascript (something similar to this):

```
$(...).change(function(event) {
    var subcategory_title = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("title");
    for(k in subcategories)
    {

    if (subcategory_title==subcategories[k].id) {
            $(this).append('<option>'+subcategories[k].name+'</option>')
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this one using ajax, Call ajax - on change event of category select box. See Below link that describe dynamic category implementation:

[jQuery ajax unlimited dynamic selectbox based on parent categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627230/jquery-ajax-unlimited-dynamic-selectbox-based-on-parent-categories)